# Visual studio 2022 function app remote debugging failure

Tags: azure, visual-studio, azure-functions, remote-debugging

I have a function app deployed into Azure and I would like to remote debug it.

- remote debugging is activated in the portal
  [image]
- I have tested 32 and 64 bit platform
- In Kudu, I can see "msvsmon.exe" running
  [image]
- I have tried manually to "attach to the process" with the port requested in the [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugger-port-assignments?view=vs-2022) regarding Visual studio versions
- I have tried from a VM in Azure
- I have deactivated firewall in the VM
- I have added an outbound rule will all permissions in the vm network settings
- I have tried with VS 2019 version and the "Cloud explorer view"
- I have tried with VS 2022 (Up to date --> Version 17.3.2) with "connected services"

[image]

And I always get this error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x89710023): Unable to
> connect to the Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugger named
> 'HOSTNAME.azurewebsites.net:4024'.  The input data was
> not in the expected format or did not have the expected value.
>
> at
> Microsoft.WebTools.Azure.VS.Operations.IDebuggerInternal120.ConnectToServer(String
> szServerName, VsDebugRemoteConnectOptions[] pConnectOptions,
> CONNECT_REASON ConnectReason, Int32 fIncrementUsageCount,
> IDebugCoreServer3& ppServer)    at
> Microsoft.WebTools.Azure.VS.Operations.RemoteDiagnosticsSessionBase`1.ConnectToServer(String
> hostNameWithPort, String user, String password)

Any idea how to fix ?

Comment: Are you getting this error in the Azure VM and also in your physical system both - Is it?

Comment: Locally, I think it's our corporate firewall the problem but in the azure VM... I don't think so

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following steps to remote debug in Visual Studio 2022:

1. Switch the remote debugging to on in Azure Portal Function App Configuration > General Settings
2. In Visual Studio 2022 Azure Functions Project, publish to Function App in the debug mode.

[image]

3. Click on `Open Site` to check the function app is up and running. And then click `Attach debugger` on Hosting options (`...`) in the VS Publish window.

It will take some time to attach the w3wp process automatically and activating the breakpoint we placed in the Function Code.

4. After activating the breakpoint, hit the Azure portal function app trigger URL in the browser, then within 2 to 3 minutes, VS will start the remote debugging as you can see in my below Gif.

[image]

Comment: I have created a new functionApp and deployed it in Azure. It works !! With my current development project, with the same configuration as the new one, it doesn't work ..., I have the error message. I have checked all the steps you mention

Comment: Are you adding `function URL:4024` in Attach to Process > Connection Target manually in Visual Studio?

Comment: When you use "Connected service", vou haven't to add it. When I attach manually I have added the `URL:4024`, in the "connect service", when it fails, it says error with error port 4024. I have tested the exact same local code in two different function app in Azure and it works on the new one, not on the previous ...... :'(

Comment: I have two resource groups. When I create a function app in RG1, all function apps failed to debug. on RG2 all work ........ ??? Any idea ?

Comment: I believe, my understanding is that function apps in RG1 failed in remote debugging and RG2 function apps are working good in remote debugging.  Is it?

Comment: Yes exactly, I just did another test. All function Apps on RG1:FAIL - RG2:SUCCESS. So I guess it's related to the Resource Group... but what could it be ...

Comment: Are you doing this in your enterprise account or personal account ( Pay-as-you-go or Free trail subscription)? because in free trail subscription, I too faced these challenges and in enterprise/organization azure account, they may kept the restrictions like you cannot create more than 3 to 4 premium hosting plans for the function apps in a single resource group.

Comment: The 2 resource groups are in an enterprise account using in both cases Consumption pricing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247598/discussion-between-hari-krishna-and-draco951).

Comment: It is asking for userid password which I have already provided when created the profile.

Comment: @Ali, Could you raise the new question with the full details and provide the link here